# How implement Spring security in RestFull application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, restful-authentication

I'm a java developer. I use Spring 4.0.1 and Hibernate 4.2.4. My application is REST FULl, even login(user send an ajax request to log in). I want to implement Spring Security, but I can't. . I tested some tutorials but I'm new on Spring and  I can't implement. I want to save my users and roles in database.

**There is no sample code**? **Can any one help me**?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security is based on filters, so it need a starting point in web.xml
like :

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping
```

>

after that comes the spring filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [demo project](https://github.com/BranislavLazic/angular-security) I made. Backend code is mostly copied from some other project I can't quite remember. Point is: User logs in via HTTP post request in order to obtain token (you can use [JWT](https://jwt.io/)). Token is stored in client side application. After that, you intercept every HTTP request and check its `Authorization` request header. Then you take its value (bearer token) and check validity. Otherwise, you reject request. 
Be careful about:

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header
- Make sure that `Authorization` header is being exposed